# How to consolidate data that is being added to every day

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, consolidation

I am trying to take data from datafile.xlsx (A1-C7) and consolidate it using the consolidate command into A1 in the same workbook, different sheet

```
Dim iwb As Workbook: Set iwb = Workbooks.Open("datafile.xlsx")
Dim insp As Worksheet: Set insp = iwb.Sheets(1)
Dim tot As Worksheet: Set tot = iwb.Sheets(2)

tot.Range("A1").consolidate _
    Sources:=Array("Inspector Data!R1C1:R7C3"), _
    Function:=xlSum, _
    TopRow:=True, _
    LeftColumn:=True
```

However, this data will grow with a new row being added each day. How do I tell the consolidate command or the array to reselect all of the data? Similar to how range.currentregion does.

Comment: is there another way of using currentregion but still using the R#C# format inside sources?

Comment: you use something from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) to find the last row and then use that in your range string.

Comment: ok so i used the
With insp
     lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
This gives me a lastrow of 7 so how exactly do i put that into the array?
I tried something like R1C1:RlastrowC3 but this does not work, do i have to put quotations?

Comment: `Sources:=Array("Inspector Data!R1C1:R" & lastrow & "C3")`

Comment: that worked exactly as i needed thank you scott!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim iwb As Workbook: Set iwb = Workbooks.Open("datafile.xlsx")
Dim insp As Worksheet: Set insp = iwb.Sheets(1)
Dim tot As Worksheet: Set tot = iwb.Sheets(2)

Dim lastrow As Long
    
With insp
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

tot.Range("A1").consolidate _
    Sources:=Array("Inspector Data!R1C1:R" & lastrow & "C3"), _
    Function:=xlSum, _
    TopRow:=True, _
    LeftColumn:=True
```